# bootstrap css, border left of fixed lenght

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am styling a page where I need three columns, and on the left of each there should be a vertical line, three lines in total, they should all have the same length.

I'm trying to implement this using a border-left css directive but my three lines get the height of the div containing them, and they have different lengths.

I would like the lines to be shorter than the column in case the column is too long, and longer in case they are short.

Please have a look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18127/ I would like the three lines to be equal size, say 100px.

There I'm getting the lines with:

```
.border-left {
  border-left: solid 2px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Should I use an SVG for the lines instead?

Thanks, 
Giulio

Comment: There's no `.border-left` class in your HTML or CSS of your fiddle. Are you sure that's the right one?

Comment: Please update your fiddle link.  It goes to a generic bootstrap fiddle.

Comment: sorry that was the wrong fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18127/ this is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element to get the desired behavior.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -20px; 
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-w-line {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.col-w-line::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-w-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-w-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit.</div>
  
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-w-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line can be, in fact, a long rectangle produced by a div background.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 4px double black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: HoneyDew;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;  
}

#b {
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: Lavender;
height: 100%;
width: 33.3%;  
}

#c {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: PaleGoldenRod;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;  
}

.line {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#a::first-letter, #b::first-letter, #c::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  
<div id=a>
<div class=line></div><span>Small text small text small text small text small text small text small text small text small text small text small text small text.</span>
</div>
  
<div id=b>
<div class=line></div><span>Medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text medium text.</span>
</div>
  
<div id=c>
<div class=line></div><span>Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text.</span>
</div>

</div>
```